# VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews React Native

Tags: react-native

hi i'm getting this error i don't know how to fix it

error type : "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain
ScrollViews with the same orientation because it can
break windowing and other functionality - use another
VirtualizedList-backed container instead."

[image]

my code

```
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <SwipeListView
        data={listData}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        renderHiddenItem={renderHiddenItem}
      
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: `SwipeListView` is a scrollable component, which has a scrolling direction. It is likely that either the item you render in `renderItem` is also scrollable in the same direction, or `SwipeListView` itself is rendered in a bigger scrollable component. Either way, react-native cannot deal with one scrollable nested in another where both scroll in the same direction (because it won't know to which component a scrolling motion belongs)

Answer (score 2):

Hello just change your react native ScrollView with this one:
Use ScrollView from react-native-virtualized-view install the package: `npm i react-native-virtualized-view` import it: `import { ScrollView } from "react-native-virtualized-view"`; and use it like you would a nomral ScrollView

Comment: This solution works without any issue. @Ons Jannet, ✅